# Neo4j Cypher Performance of Optional Match

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to write a query to count the total number of votes for an election grouped by the state in which they were cast.  **I'd like all states to be returned even if there are 0 votes.**  The following query uses optional match to return all states regardless of whether or not any votes have been cast.

```
MATCH (state:State)
OPTIONAL MATCH (state)<-[:FROM]-(:User)-[:CAST]->(vote:Vote)-[:FOR]->(:Election{id:'ABC123'})
RETURN state, count(vote)
```

**returns 50 rows in in 3064ms**.

If I remove the optional match the query performs much better :

```
MATCH (state:State),(state)<-[:FROM]-(:User)-[:CAST]->(vote:Vote)-[:FOR]->(:Election{id:'ABC123'})
RETURN state, count(*)
```

**returns 49 rows in 406ms**.

My questions are

1. Why is there such a huge discrepancy in performance between the two queries ?
2. Is there a better way to structure the query to improve performance and still meet the requirement?

Comment: Are you sure there is a discrepency between these queries?  During your first couple queries after you launch the shell, other things are happening (like pre-populating a cache, and so on).   Be careful to run both repeatedly before you decide what's fast and what's slow, to get rid of differences that come from hot/cold cache.

Comment: I ran each query about 4 times and posted the times of the last respective runs.

Answer (score 0):

What about using a Union statement?:

> MATCH (s:State) 
>   RETURN s  
>   UNION 
>   MATCH (s:State)<-[:FROM]-(:User)-[:CAST]->(vote:Vote)-[:FOR]->(:Election{id:'ABC123'})
>   RETURN s, count(vote)

I think your query may be taking so long due to the mechanics of the optional match vis a vis the count(vote) operation. I'm not sure if this will be faster, but it might be worth a try.

[Union Docs](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/query-union.html) 

[Optional Match Docs](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/query-optional-match.html)